# Caching efficiency of using a lot of static variables and template metaprogramming C++

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, static-variables

Suppose I have the C++ code below

```
template <int Id>
struct Foo {
    static inline int x {};
};

int main() {
    using T0 = Foo<0>;
    using T1 = Foo<1>;
    ...
    using T999 = Foo<999>;
    // Do some stuff with the various x's at runtime
    int result = T0::x + T1::x + ... + T999::x;
}
```

Now inspect the sum in the final line. Is there any guarantee that the various static x's will be stored contiguously in memory and that this sum will be efficient cache wise? Or in general should one assume that the static variables are just stored in some random order in random places in such a way that would not be cache efficient.

In the case of the former is it because the using statements appear in order? Does template instantiation occur because of the presence of a using statement or does the template actually have to be used (in which case maybe they are stored in usage order)?

In the case of the latter would using a tuple of size 1000 and each Foo::x using the n-th index in that tuple as its variable solve that problem?

Comment: *should one assume that the static variables are just stored in some random order* Yes, one should do. https://godbolt.org/z/eYhdWh5M6 - as you can see, the order is unspecified if `Foo`'s are instantiated somewhere else.

Comment: You ask too much questions in a single post. The SO rule is: one post - one question.

Comment: A to Q#1:  **no**.  A to Q#2: **no**, profile profile profile your optimized code to assess.  A to Q#3: **n/a**.  A to Q#4: unsure, I think they have to be used.  A to Q#5: not sure, you'd have to look at the generated code.

Comment: *Some order* may be enforceable, based on the used linker. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E26506/chapter2-90421.html#chapter2-12) chapter *Tentative Symbol Order Within the Output File*. But that doesn't work well with template instantiations (or `inline` in general, I think)

Comment: Hmm, maybe a common base class with a `std::array<int, 1000>`, and the template derived from that class, with the template argument specifying the index?

Comment: What is your C++ standard.

Comment: What is the problem your trying to solve? and how should this code actually solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Template aliases like `using T0 = Foo<0>;` do not instantiate templates.

```
int result = T0::x + T1::x + ... + T999::x;
```

The evaluation order of arguments is unspecified. Hence, the template instantiation order is also unspecified.

https://godbolt.org/z/rzWvjbEaT

```
func():
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR Foo<1>::x[rip]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR Foo<0>::x[rip]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR Foo<999>::x[rip]
        ret
Foo<999>::x:
        .long   999
Foo<1>::x:
        .long   1
Foo<0>::x:
        .zero   4
```

The access order: 1, 0, 999. The in memory order: 999, 1, 0.

If you need a specific order, use arrays and loops.

Answer (score 1):

Although it might be the case for it to be allocated contigously, it's not actually guaranteed. It's better to create an array and make constant indexes to refer to particular fragments, e.g. `const variable7_ind = 7` and then use `T[variable7_ind]` instead of `T7`.

Answer (score -1):

The code is

```
#include <iostream>

template <int Idx>
struct Foo {
  static inline int x{};
};

template <int Idx>
struct Bar {
  static inline int x{};
};

int main() {
  using A = Foo<0>;
  using B = Foo<1>;
  using C = Foo<2>;
  using D = Bar<0>;
  std::cout << &B::x << std::endl;
  std::cout << &C::x << std::endl;
  std::cout << &D::x << std::endl;
  std::cout << &A::x << std::endl;
}
```

My system is:

```
Homebrew clang version 17.0.6
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

And the output is

```
0x100dc4000
0x100dc4004
0x100dc4008
0x100dc400c
```

From this we can conclude that the sum will be efficient as long as the

```
// Do some stuff with the various x's at runtime
```

uses the different x's in order as that is the same order in which they will be stored in memory. It is based on order of usage not order of the `using` statements

NOTE I don't know if this is the case on all systems, but that is how it seems to be behaving on mine. Print stuff out and profile on yours to make sure

Comment: You code basically is not the same as in the question. `std::cout << &B::x << std::endl; std::cout << &C::x << std::endl; std::cout << &D::x << std::endl; td::cout << &A::x << std::endl;` the evaluation and instantiation orders are hardcoded. `B::x + C::x + D::x + A::x` prior the output would give the unspecified order.

Comment: It's how the data is stored on your system with this exact code on your particular compiler and its current compiler settings and on Sunday. Or was that the Saturday version? Oh, probably not, since the question wasn't posted before Sunday.

Comment: Side issue: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).